# The type or namespace name '' could not be found

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf

I've made a simple WCF Service Application to call my database. But when i added it to my Web App as a Service Reference it gives me the compilation Error of "The type or namespace name 'WebServiceNamespace' could not be found".

The name space isn't the same as any class name so that solution is crossed out.

I've already un-ticked 'Reuse types in referenced assemblies' in my service reference configuration settings.

It may have to do with the automatically generated code when i added the web service reference but i don't know what part of the generated code is causing it.

FYI i'm running the web service locally.

Comment: Try the knownType property

Comment: @LuffyDing Like what this guy has done [here](http://blog.rebuildall.net/2010/11/10/wcf_service_namespaces)

Comment: Could you share your wcf interface? Can you execute and consume your service, for instance, using wcf test client?